# Последовательное прохождение пути

Tags: javascript

Имеется простой пример: codepen.io/anon/pen/WxONkk

Щёлкая по траве можно заметить, что красный квадрат двигается не последовательно, а телепортами.

В интернете нашёл следующее демо: http://www.briangrinstead.com/files/astar-original/

И в демке всё работает как надо, но можно ли применить технологию которая в демо к моему примеру?

В примере canvas а у меня обычные div
Благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: вместо мгновенного перемещения в указанную координату -  разбиваете перемещение к координате на движение по горизонтали и вертикали.....и дальше просто анимируете сий переход по одной оси и затем по другой... за `N` шагов... на каждом шаге оставляете клон квадратика, который уничтожаете через `M` миллисекунд

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку tweenjs
https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js

Answer (score 1):

Надо держать текущие координаты куба, и координаты цели. Пока кубу до цели есть, куда двигаться, работает таймер, который за 1 раз двигает куб на 1 шаг: по горизонтали или вертикали. Если надо двигаться наискосок, он случайно выбирает либо горизонтальный либо вертикальный ход. Для сглаживания движения используется CSS3 свойство `transition`:

```js
var tile = {
    w: 32,
    h: 32
  },
  map = {
    w: 29,
    h: 24
  },
  x, y, div, i = 0,
  cube = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    el: document.getElementById('cube')
  };

for (y = 0; y <= map.h; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x <= map.w; x++) {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'tile_' + x + '_' + y + '_0');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'tile');
    div.setAttribute('style', 'top: ' + (y * tile.h) + 'px; left: ' + (x * tile.w) + 'px;');
    map001.appendChild(div);
  }
}
var target = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  timer;
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('tile')) {
    move(e.target);
  }
});

function move(tile) {
  var id = tile.id.split('_');
  target.x = parseInt(id[1]);
  target.y = parseInt(id[2]);
  if (!timer) timer = window.setInterval(step, 100);
}

function step() {
  var dx = Math.sign(target.x - cube.x),
    dy = Math.sign(target.y - cube.y);

  if (!dx && !dy) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
    timer = undefined;
    return;
  }
  if (dx && dy) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      dx = 0;
    } else {
      dy = 0;
    }
  }

  cube.x += dx;
  cube.y += dy;

  cube.el.style.transform = 'translate(' + (cube.x * tile.w) + 'px,' + (cube.y * tile.h) + 'px)';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map001 {
  width: 960px;
  height: 800px;
}
#map001 div {
  background: url(http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/BD/F6/d86cd1eb00f1bdf6.png);
  z-index: 0;
}
#cube {
  background: #939;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
#map001 div,
#cube {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id='cube'></div>
<div id='map001'></div>
```